# How to not display a column that has all NULL values in a file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, columns

I have a file that has let's say, 5 columns(obtained by redirecting the results of a Sybase select query). Each column is separated by a tab. I need to filter out the columns that have all NULLs. Any column among the five can be null.

For example, if the columns in the file look like the below:

```
1000    NULL    NULL    2       NULL
7       NULL    1000    2       NULL
7       NULL    1000    2       NULL
7       NULL    1000    2       NULL
7       NULL    1000    2       NULL
7       NULL    1000    2       NULL
7       NULL    1000    2       NULL
7       NULL    1000    2       NULL
7       NULL    1000    2       NULL
7       NULL    1000    2       NULL
7       NULL    1000    2       NULL
7       NULL    1000    2       NULL
7       NULL    1000    2       NULL
7       NULL    1000    2       NULL
7       NULL    1000    2       NULL
7       NULL    1000    2       NULL
7       NULL    1000    2       NULL
7       NULL    1000    2       NULL
7       NULL    1000    2       NULL
7       NULL    1000    2       NULL
7       NULL    1000    2       NULL
```

The output must be(after removing columns 2 and 5), preferably in the same file:

```
1000    NULL    2    
7       1000    2    
7       1000    2    
7       1000    2    
7       1000    2    
7       1000    2    
7       1000    2    
7       1000    2    
7       1000    2    
7       1000    2    
7       1000    2    
7       1000    2    
7       1000    2    
7       1000    2    
7       1000    2    
7       1000    2    
7       1000    2    
7       1000    2    
7       1000    2    
7       1000    2    
7       1000    2
```

I reached:

```
for i in {1..5}  
do
echo $i
dlr="$"$i
str="{print $dlr}"
echo $str
awk '$str' <input_file> | while read value
    do
        echo $value

        if [ "$value" == "NULL" ]
        then
                echo "inside"
                cut $i 
        fi
    done
done
```

value right now, shows all the rows!!!
Also, I am not sure how to cut off the column. I am a shell script beginner and unable to proceed further.

Can you please advise how to do this?

Comment: Would it not be easier to do this in the database query?

Comment: It doesn't feel like a particularly easy thing to do in SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really like this solution but it seems to work:

```
#!/bin/bash

input=~/tmp/input
skip=()

c=$(awk '{print NF;exit}' "$input")

for ((i=1;i<=c;i++)); do
    col=$(awk -v c="$i" '{print $c}' "$input" | sort -u)
    if [[ $col == NULL ]]; then
        skip+=( "$i" )
    fi
done
( IFS=,; awk -v S="${skip[*]}" '{ split(S,s,","); for (i=1;i<=length(s);i++) { $s[i]="" } print}' "$input" )
```

1. `input` (your input file)
2. `skip` (array that will be filled later)
3. `c` (will be set to the number of columns in your file.  This assumes the entire file has a uniform number of columns)
4. We now will loop through each column in the file, sort and unique it, and check if the column only contains `NULL`.  If so we will add that column number to the `skip` array
5. We now set the `IFS` to a comma (the reason I'm using a subshell) and pass the `skip` array as a comma separated value to an `awk` variable.  This is so we can use `split` to convert that variable back into an `awk` array.
6. `awk` will then loop through each number in the `s` array and set that column to empty and print what remains.

Answer (score 3):

By means of the [GNU utility `datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/), you first invert the rows then delete all null rows and invert the rows once again:

```
$ datamash transpose | sed -Ee '/^(NULL\t)*NULL$/d' | datamash transpose
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it without processing the file twice. The following is first using `awk` to construct the final `cut` command:

```
killnulls(){
    cut -f "$(awk -F'\t' '
        { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i] += $i!="NULL" }
        END { for(i=1;i in a;i++) if(a[i]) printf j++?","i:i }
    ' "$@")" "$@"
}

$ killnulls file
1000    NULL    2
7       1000    2
7       1000    2
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Command:

```
awk '/NULL/{gsub(/NULL/,"",$0);print $0}' filename| sed -r "s/\s+/ /g"| awk 'NR==1{$3=$2;$2="NULL";}1'
```

output

```
awk '/NULL/{gsub(/NULL/,"",$0);print $0}' i.txt| sed -r "s/\s+/ /g"| awk 'NR==1{$3=$2;$2="NULL";}1'
1000 NULL 2
7 1000 2 
7 1000 2 
7 1000 2 
7 1000 2 
7 1000 2 
7 1000 2 
7 1000 2 
7 1000 2 
7 1000 2 
7 1000 2 
7 1000 2 
7 1000 2 
7 1000 2 
7 1000 2 
7 1000 2 
7 1000 2 
7 1000 2 
7 1000 2 
7 1000 2 
7 1000 2
```